# How to find next value with condition in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which is updated with live data every minute.
Once a new row has been added, the first one will be deleted.
So I always have a steady df size.

dataframe column:

```
frac_lows_rsi

...
50    0.000
51   49.747
52    0.000
53   47.747
54    0.000
55    0.000
56    0.000
57   45.834
58    0.000
59    0.000
```

Row 59 gets the live data and after each minute the dataframe shifts.
Now, I need to check for the value in the second last row and compare it to the next value if not 0. The distance of rows between value in [-2] and the next always varies.
I also can not use a loop.

Desired output is `True` if value in frac_lows_rsi[-2] is smaller than the next value (> 0)

I tried it this way:

```
df['signal'] = df['frac_lows_rsi'].iloc[-2].gt(max((x) for x in df['frac_lows_rsi'] if x > 0))
```

But i get an error and I'm not sure if I'm on the right path:

```
'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'gt'
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Your immediate problem is that you extracted a `float` scalar from the df; this is a simple Python float, *not* a PANDAS object.  Therefore, you have to use `>` instead of the PANDAS operation `gt`.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: ditto from above. Also what do you mean compare to the next?

Comment: With next I mean the the first value (>0),  when u go up the rows. In this example 47.747. It seems to work with the `<`. I let it run for while...

Comment: Unfortunately I get always a `False`value even if the condition is `true`